# Stretching an image in CSS with page resize

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I'm learning how to do CSS and I'm working backwards from a template that can scale images when the window is resized. The class which I think has this effect in the template is this one:

```
.project-link {
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-color: #adadad;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 80%;
    }
    .circle .project-link, .circle .project-link .hover {
        border-radius: 100%;
        -moz-border-radius: 100%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    }
    .project-link .hexagon-top {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        border-left-color: #dfdfdf;
        border-right-color: #dfdfdf;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .project-link .hexagon-bottom {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-left-color: #dfdfdf;
        border-right-color: #dfdfdf;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }
        .project-link .hover {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            background: #ec6136;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            display: block;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all .3s;
            -moz-transition: all .3s;
            -webkit-transitin: all .3s;
        }
            .project-link .hover-text {
                display: block;
                margin-top: 45%;
            }
            .project-link .hover-text:after {
                content: '>';
                font-family: 'icon';
                font-size: 12px;
                margin-left: 15px;
            }
        .project-link:hover > .hover {
            opacity: .9;
        }
```

My code for a similar class is as follows:

```
.HS {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 283px;
height: 213px;
background: url(http://www.hugoproject.com/ftp1/images/icons.png) no-repeat;
```

}

```
.HS span {
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
background: url(http://www.hugoproject.com/ftp1/images/icons.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 0 -214px;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
-moz-transition:    opacity 0.5s;
-o-transition:      opacity 0.5s;
```

}

```
.HS:hover span {
opacity: 1;
```

}

Could you please point me in the direction of where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: you've missed the css for `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

Basically your question is not much clear. But based on my understanding here's the thing.

If you look at the example code you have provided from the template it uses percentage values for width. So the width of those elements always stays in proportion to the browser size.

E.g. Check width: 80%; in following class

```
.project-link {
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-color: #adadad;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 80%;
    }
```

Using percentage values is one of the ways to create responsive designs.

Comment: Thanks for that - to clarify the page I am trying is here:

http://www.hugoproject.com/test.html

Note the left most image doesnt scale like the ones on the right

I can't change the image width values to a % as I'm using a sprite and that messes it up